# 2 axes scrolling tiled "map" view (TiledScrollView)

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a tiled close-up map view that scrolls along both axes, with 3 zoom levels, similiar to the iOS CATiledLayer.  The map is for a very small space, with points of interest separated by feet rather than miles, so a google maps application wouldn't work.  Imagine a floorplan of an individual building.

I found this: https://github.com/ened/Android-Tiling-ScrollView, which initially looked like exactly what I wanted, but haven't had any success with it.  There are notes in the source that it's a "Library Project", which I've never used (I'm fairly new to Android development).  If I try to import it, Eclipse complains that it's not a project file.  If I build a new project from existing source, it is listed as a Library project but then many other errors appear (several errors complain about attributes - I can't remember the exact wording).

Has anyone had any success with the library linked above?  If not, are there any gotchas I should be aware of as regards Library projects in general?  Searching on Library projects yielded a little documentation, but none of the approaches I found worked with that particular library specifically.  Does a Libary project need to exist relative to the project using it in a specific way (e.g., does it need to be nested)?

TYIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new Android project.
2. Copy all the java files from `sample` and `library` folders src to your new project src folder.
3. Similarly copy all other resources like assets, xml files etc to new project.
4. You are done!.

Comment: thanks - I actually figured this one out a while ago but forgot to close this question.